# How to load certain portion of file into memory and write it on a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, file

I have a csv file which generates dataframe for every second and stores it in it. It will have millions of values. How to load only certain part. Like only first 5 MB. Then next 5 MB in a text file.. How to load certain portion of file in memory and write it in text file?

Comment: That's why this kind of design is flawed.  You can skip forward to any multiple of 5MB, but you have no idea if you're in the middle of a line or not.  This data should be in a database.

Comment: if you use `pandas.read_csv` then it has option to read some number of rows. And you can run it with `for`-loop to repeat it.